# How to retrieve Image from specific row using with Nth Row in Conga?

Tags: community, conga

I have table that store image url together with other data.I want to display it together with other data in PowerPoint.I know that I need to use {{IMAGE:URL_PICTURE}}.But with this,how I can know this image belong to its row?

Example:
Jane     Photo    1234

So I write something like this

```
{{MyData.EmployeeName.0}} {{IMAGE:MyData.EmployeePhoto.0}}{{MyData.EmployeeId.0}}
```

It display correctly,except for image.I cannot use TableStart and TableEnd because Conga limit only one TableStart per slide,while user request two tables per slide.Luckily the data row is fixed(the sample data above just for illustration only).Any idea how I am going to display the image in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Merging images from multiple datasets to a single PowerPoint slide isn't supported by Conga Composer.  However, you can absolutely accomplish this in a Microsoft Word template using Composer.  Do you have flexibility in the type of template format you're working with?

As I mentioned in a response to one of your previous posts, the Conga Support team will be the best resource to help you with these kinds of questions that are very specific to our applications.  Please feel free to contact our team anytime - we'd love to help out over a screen share!  http://congasphere.com/live-support.html